# woocommerce api for variation stock update by variation id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-quantity, product-variations

I want to update Woocommerce variation product stock by using `variation id`.

I tried but that update only main `inventory Stock quantity` not updating variations quantity. This is my code:

```
$product_id = 7559;
$variance_id = 122;
$get_stocks = $woocommerce->get('products/'.$product_id);
$stock_quantity_old = $get_stocks["stock_quantity"];
$data = [
        'stock_quantity' => $stock_quantity_old - 1
    ];
$result = $woocommerce->put('products/'.$product_id, $data);
```

This code only updates the main inventory stock quantity.
I want to update variation quantity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to set `manage_stock` to true then use `stock_quantity`.please use below code.

```
$product_id = 7559;
$variance_id = 122;
$get_stocks = $woocommerce->get('products/'.$product_id);
$stock_quantity_old = $get_stocks["stock_quantity"];
$data = [
        'manage_stock' => true,
        'stock_quantity' => $stock_quantity_old - 1
    ];
$result = $woocommerce->put('products/'.$product_id.'/variations/'.$variance_id, $data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now your code reducing only main stock quantity. Actually i want to reduce `$variance_id = 122` quantity